# Obtain status code returned by PhantomJS to Selenium driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am working on Java code which uses Selenium Web Driver with PhantomJS as the browser to access sites.

My requirement is that I should be able to retrieve the status code returned by every site. After going through several available posts it seems that Selenium Web Driver does not have this provision. But PhantomJS has the `OnResourceReceived` API that returns the status code.

How would I be able to use `OnResourceReceived` along with Selenium Web Driver. Can anyone help me out on this? Or any other alternate work around that will give me the status code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FiddlerCore to get HTTP statuscodes. This excellent guide explains how to do this with selenium webdriver: 
http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/implementing-webdriver-http-status.html